# how to call a method through a 2d array error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a new list so that whatever the user enters into the altitude this method should look for the coordinates and return the coordinates below what user has entered. I'm struggling to get this method to run.

```
static double[][] array;
Map m = new Map();

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    m.coordinatesBelow(-2000)
}

public static void readDataArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.xyz")));
    int rows = 2500000;
    int columns = 3;

    double[][] array= new double[rows][columns];
    int i = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] line = input.nextLine().trim().split("\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(line[j]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
}

public List<Double> coordinatesBelow(double altitude) {
    List<Double> coordinatesBelow = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        coordinatesBelow.add(array[i][2]);
    }
    coordinatesBelow.removeIf(b -> b > altitude);
    return coordinatesBelow;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've missed those bits when putting them in. I have declared array but array of earth is meant to be array, I've change it now. Basically sample.xyz has 3 columns longitude, latitude and altitude and I'm trying to create a list for when the altitude is lower then the input lets say -2000 which means I need all the coordinates below the altitudes (-2000) to be removed from the list.

Comment: Instead of using coordinatesBelow.removeIf later, you should check if the coordinates are valid right when you're adding them in, to make your program faster.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to do this? Sorry I'm quite new to java

Comment: ```List<Double> coordinatesBelow = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i][2] < altitude) coordinatesBelow.add(array[i][2]);
        }```

Comment: Thanks for that, Just one more issue, My file doesn't seem to be looping through this method. Do you know if I can get my file to read my method. Whenever I compile it I get an java.lang.NullPointerException on this line ```for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {``` on the coordinatesBelow method.

Comment: yes, I have changed that. I think the issue is that the method can't find the sample.xyz so it doesn't read the file. Is their a way I can add this file from the method readDataArray to coordinatesBelow(). or is this another kind of error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your entire class here

Comment: Hi, This is all I have in my class at the moment, I didn't add my main part because all it does is calls the method. I've added it now though.

Comment: @d_johnstone please look at my updated answer

Comment: @KirillSimonov Thanks for this, its solved my issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `static double[][] array;` declared at the first line and `double[][] array = new double[rows][columns];` are 2 different variables: the first is static, the second is local. So when you read the values into the local `array` the static one remains empty.

If you want to save the values into the static array, don't create a new variable, just initialize the static array in your static method - change

```
double[][] array = new double[rows][columns];
```

to

```
array = new double[rows][columns];
```

**UPD:** If you are getting a `NullPointerException` at the line `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`, the only thing that can be `null` here is `array`. So make sure the `array` is initialized before you call `coordinatesBelow`. And you initialize it in the `readDataArray` method, so try calling it first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    readDataArray("filename.txt");
    m.coordinatesBelow(-2000);
}
```

Bu the way, it looks like the `filename` argument is not used anywhere, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling coordinatesBelow as a method of Map. Is this correct? This would need to be a class that you have created yourself like so:

```
private static class Map {
        public List<Double> coordinatesBelow(double altitude) {
            List<Double> coordinatesBelow = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                coordinatesBelow.add(array[i][2]);
            }
            coordinatesBelow.removeIf(b -> b > altitude);
            return coordinatesBelow;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help and suggestion. I would like the coordinatesBelow method to be in the same class as the readDataArray method. I'm quite new to java and have just realised that I don't need the ```Map m = new Map();``` in my code as its not coming from another class so I'm really sorry if I've confused you by putting that in.